# How do i create api keys for users on my client instead of developer portal offered in azure api management?

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an enpoint in my MERN app which I would like to expose to developers. 
I came across APIM and would like to use it.
After going to the documentation I would like to know how do I can use APIM for my specific enpoint and where I allow users to generate API's in my client side react app.

I am also going through the API management API. but don't know how to generate user specific API keys...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply mimic what the Developer Portal does using APIMs REST API.

If you are using the Consumption Tier of APIM, you can just create a standalone subscription using the [Create or Update Subscription API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/createorupdate). Yon don't have to set `properties.ownerId` in the request payload here.

On the other tiers, standalone subscriptions are not supported yet (but will be as mentioned in the [official announcement blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-api-management-for-serverless-architectures/) under New Features), so you will have to create a user first using the [Create or Update User API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/createorupdate) and then create a new subscription mentioning this user under `properties.ownerId` as `/users/{userId}`.

Since these REST APIs call the Azure Management API, you shouldn't be making these requests from the client and instead should be calling this from your backend.